# How i can display article filter by age in expressionengine

Tags: search, filter, expressionengine, channel

I have some article in expression engine now i want to display article filter by age range like (1-10 ,10-20 etc..) and cost wise like(low,medium,high) so please guide me how i can do filtration of article...
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can you show us?

Comment: @AllInOne we used use Solspace Super Search module for filters you can also try this module http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/